# R 4, tidyverse install issue, no httr package

Tags: r, tidyverse, httr

I did a fresh install of R and RStudio today, and now tidy verse will not load, including when I specify (or don't specify) the lib for the install and the load. Have restarted multiple times, each time the issue is that "there is no package called 'httr'". Code example:

```
install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE, lib = "/Users/Darcy/Library/R/4.0/library")
library(tidyverse, lib = "/Users/Darcy/Library/R/4.0/library")
```

and resulting failure (complete):

```
> install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE, lib = "/Users/Darcy/Library/R/4.0/library")
also installing the dependency ‘httr’


  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
     binary source needs_compilation
httr  1.4.1  1.4.2             FALSE

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/tidyverse_1.3.0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 433049 bytes (422 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 422 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/rl/vd2lvhf96fd9d69qvmc9pys00000gq/T//Rtmpj5S5Yc/downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘httr’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/httr_1.4.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 159950 bytes (156 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 156 KB

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/INSTALL: line 34:  1057 Done                    echo 'tools:::.install_packages()'
      1058 Abort trap: 6           | R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES= LC_COLLATE=C "${R_HOME}/bin/R" $myArgs --no-echo --args ${args}
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/rl/vd2lvhf96fd9d69qvmc9pys00000gq/T/Rtmpj5S5Yc/downloaded_packages’
> library(tidyverse, lib = "/Users/Darcy/Library/R/4.0/library")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘httr’
```

Comment: Have you tried installing httr?

Comment: Yes. Still has the same error pop up.

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow. Could you share the exact error when you try and install **httr** with `install.packages("httr").

Comment: Note that R 4.0 requires macOS 10.13 or higher. These error messages make it seem like you might be running an older version of the OS. You should either update your OS or run an older version of R.

Comment: There is no error when I try and install httr with install.packages("httr"), the error only appears when I try to load tidyverse. I can load the individual necessary packages separately.

Seems like I need to get an older version of R.

Answer (score 0):

My iMac computer cannot update any more, but switching to R3.6.3 (El Capitan) was an effective solution.

I mistakenly updated my R from 3.4.2 to 4.0.2, which was too far.